# Exception Error When Writing to Text Files using Scanners

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I am teaching myself java and I have been experimenting with Scanners and Writing to text files. When I use this code it throws an error message.

```
    package testPackage;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class WriteTest1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        String name; 
        String cont;
        Scanner nameSc = new Scanner(System.in); //Gets the name of the file that is being edited.
        Scanner contSc = new Scanner(System.in); //Gets the content that is being added to the file.
        name = nameSc.next(); //First scanner's input
        cont = contSc.next(); //Second scanner's input
        Formatter file = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\MyDesktop\\" +name);
        file.format("%s",cont);
        file.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
}
```

I have tried changing the exception type to `}catch(FileNotFoundException e){`but it continued to throw the error message.

Next I tried to see if it was one of the scanners/strings. I found that the specific error was caused by the `Formatter file = new Formatter("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\MyDesktop\\" +name);`.
If I remove the last set of \ it works fine but, it puts the file in the wrong location and if I leave them in it says Error and does nothing.(Fixed)

*Edit* My new problem is in the `file.format("%s",cont);` line. When I put in a sentence it only prints the first word. I know that the problem is in the `"%s"`. However, in reading the information on the oracle it seems that I cannot use the `.format` to do this.

*Edit 2* I tried replacing `file.format("%s", cont);`with `file.format("%s", "String Test");`. And it worked the file contained both words. But, that doesn't let a user set the content that is going to be written.

What do I use?

Comment: Why do you think you need two `Scanner` instances for the same input source?

Comment: add a `e.printStackTrace()` before `System.out.println("Error");`, and post the ouput

Comment: The problem with the `Formatter` line was that I had left a character off of my username in the file path. Now it only prints the first word of my `file.format("%s ",cont);`

Comment: It doesn't output anything. the problem is that `Scanner` doesn't accept spaces and when one is in the input it cuts off everything after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the last set of \ it will name the file Desktop*name* so you need them.

try logging the error, use `e.printStackTrace()` or `System.out.println(e.getMessage()` in the chatch to print the error

Comment: The problem wasn't what I thought it was. I had a typo in the file path.